What movie had a nazi soldier force a mother to chose between her two children?
Sometime in the late 80's/ early 90's I saw a World War II movie with an intense scene involving a mother with a son and younger daughter. She was in line perhaps evacuating when a Nazi soldier made her pick which child to keep and which to give up. I believe she gave up the daughter. 
I thought about that scene from time to time my whole life, especially after having children.

Sophie's Choice. Here's the relevant part of the plot as described on Wikipedia:

She reveals to him that, upon arrival at Auschwitz, she was forced to
  choose which one of her two children would be gassed and which would
  proceed to the labor camp. To avoid having both children killed, she
  chose her son, Jan, to be sent to the children's camp, and her
  daughter, Eva, to be sent to her death.

